# stdio data from write not making it into a file

Tags: c, file-io, stdio

I'm having a problem with using stdio commands for manipulating data in a file. I short, when I write data into a file, write returns an int indicating that it was successful, but when I read it back out I only get the old data.

Here's a stripped down version of the code:

```
fd = open(filename,O_RDWR|O_APPEND);

struct dE *cDE = malloc(sizeof(struct dE));

//Read present data
printf("\nreading values at %d\n",off);
printf("SeekStatus <%d>\n",lseek(fd,off,SEEK_SET));
printf("ReadStatus  <%d>\n",read(fd,cDE,deSize));

printf("current Key/Data <%d/%s>\n",cDE->key,cDE->data);

printf("\nwriting new values\n");
//Change the values locally 
cDE->key  = //something new
cDE->data = //something new

//Write them back
printf("SeekStatus  <%d>\n",lseek(fd,off,SEEK_SET));
printf("WriteStatus <%d>\n",write(fd,cDE,deSize));

//Re-read to make sure that it got written back
printf("\nre-reading values at %d\n",off);
printf("SeekStatus <%d>\n",lseek(fd,off,SEEK_SET));
printf("ReadStatus  <%d>\n",read(fd,cDE,deSize));

printf("current Key/Data <%d/%s>\n",cDE->key,cDE->data);
```

Furthermore, here's the dE struct in case you're wondering:

```
struct dE {
    int key;
    char data[DataSize];
};
```

This prints:

```
reading values at 1072
SeekStatus <1072>
ReadStatus  <32>
current Key/Data <27/old>

writing new values
SeekStatus  <1072>
WriteStatus <32>

re-reading values at 1072
SeekStatus <1072>
ReadStatus  <32>
current Key/Data <27/old>
```

Comment: Does `read((*fd).fd,cDE,deSize);` compile cleanly?  Also, to dereference pointers use `->`, ie `cDE->key`.

Comment: You never set the values of the variables `offset` and `deSize`, so they might be anything.  You never check the return values of `read`, `write`, or `lseek`.  You need to post a stripeed down COMPILABLE version of your code that demonstates the problem you are having or the question you are asking.  90% of the time, the excercise of creating that compilable example will answer the question for you.

Comment: Do you have permissions on the directory and the file?

Comment: I suspect `(*cDE).data = //something new` isn't doing what you want - you probably need `strncpy`.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm still new to StackOverflow and coming up with a concise query isn't something that comes to me naturally yet. 

I updated my code with the output. Everything in here compiles, and I cleaned up my formatting a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `|O_APPEND` from the `open` call.

Comment: That did it! That was a huge oversight... from the 'man 2 open', under 'O_APPEND' : "Before each write(2) the file offset is positioned at the end of the file as if with lseek(2)"